# To create a relationship between characters of string java

Tags: java

I have a string list

```
[A,x,y,B,z,C,r]
```

The uppercase characters are Models

```
[A,B,C]
```

The lowercase characters are subModel

```
[x,y,z,r]
```

The lower case characters have delay of

```
x= 5, y=10, z= 15, r = 20
```

The last subModel of a model should represent the delay of that Model that is delay of

```
A = 10, B = 15, r = 20
```

the number of subModels can change for a certain model, so the algorithm should be that the last delay time of the subModel of a Model should be Model's delay time.

Could you help me to find a relationship or algorithm to perform the followig?

Comment: Show me your code..What have you tried

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i can help you with this. What you are looking for is called inheritance.Now im not to sure what you are getting at with the delay times but If i were you i would make a class for all the models and sub-models (you can use a simple if/else or switch statement to figure out what string goes with what model). Now it looks like your sub-models are the ones with the values, so i would actually have the models inherit from their sub-models. Code should look something like this

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]){
    ModelA a = new ModelA();
    SubModelB b = new SubModelB(); 
    System.out.print(b.getVlaue()) ; 

   }
}


public class ModelA extends Main {
    public static int delay = 10 ; 
    public int getVlaue(){
        return value;
    }

}



public class SubModelB extends ModelA {
    public int getVlaue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more help